# Delete App History in Task Manager (Windows 8.1)

Tags: windows-8, history

[image: App History, Task Manager, Windows 8.1]
How do I delete the apps from the App History tab? With the exception of "Google Chrome", I hardly use any of the listed apps...and there are several applications I use regularly which don't appear at all (like Paint and Visual Studio 2013). I've definitely NOT opened "Maps" and "Sound Recorder" for more than 3 months and that was just testing out the new laptop. When I click "Delete usage history", the list does not change.

I'd like the App History tab to actually work...or to remove the tab altogether. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### "How do I delete the apps from the App History tab?"

The App History tab shows the total resources used by apps since Windows was installed or **since the last time the usage history was deleted.**

---

#### "There are several applications I use regularly which don't appear at all (like Paint and Visual Studio 2013"

To display usage for all processes:

- "Options" > "Show history for all processes"

---

#### "When I click "Delete usage history", the list does not change."

It **did** change, by clearing the history **data** to `0` as shown in your screenshot. This is the intended behaviour. See below for more information.

---

#### How to Show Historical Data for all Windows 8 Processes

> By default, the App History tab will only display usage for modern
>   Windows 8 apps. To get the most use from this tab, click or tap
>   "Options" and select "Show history for all processes."
>
> [image]

...

> **How to Clear your App History Data**
>
> When viewing your app history data, it can be difficult to discern how
>   quickly your apps are racking up network usage. You may see that
>   Netflix has used gigs of data, but if that’s over a long period that
>   may not be so bad. However, if it’s only been a few minutes since data
>   logging began, you’re in trouble.
>
> If you want to clear your data and start counting again from zero, go
>   ahead and click or tap "Delete usage history."
>
> [image]
>
> The Windows 8 Task Manager - Which Apps Use the Most System Resources?
>
> All of your recorded history will be deleted and all columns will be
>   zeroed out. With careful monitoring you can now see how quickly your
>   heavy users chew up data.
>
> [image]

Source [The Windows 8 Task Manager - Which Apps Use the Most Resources?](http://www.7tutorials.com/windows-8-task-manager-which-apps-use-most-system-resources)

Comment: OK thanks, that works as described. In my opinion, the functionality is a little unpolished and would benefit from the ability to allow the user to choose which apps are monitored (or even to switch app monitoring off altogether).